# How to make absolutely positioned image same size (in %, responsive) than same image underneath

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I have a static and active version of a gif, the static version is absolutely positioned over the other so that when I hover it, it dissapears and the gif plays. But I can't figure out how to make them the exact same size in a way that is responsive.

I have tried different approaches on how to size them, but, none of them are responsive enough

This codepen has the code, it's really simple and short.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErXvXb

this is the html, i deleted the other 2 columns so that its not distracting, but the idea is to get it to work on the 3 columns

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:2rem 2rem;min-height:100vh;display: flex;align-items: center;">
  <div class="row" style="display: flex;align-items: start;">
  <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
    <img class="static" style="width: 85%;" src="http://nodorojo.com/img/responsive.png"><img class="active" style="width: 85%;" src="http://nodorojo.com/img/responsive.gif">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, distinctio, cum iusto esse pariatur consectetur eligendi itaque quos totam voluptas rem mollitia voluptatem veniam reiciendis omnis, saepe eaque animi qui.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.static {
  position: absolute;
}

.static:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: you should use javascript to do this.For now both image are on page.Just overlapping each other but if you use javascript like on hover change image to gif then it will be easy for you to set width and thats the correct way for replacing image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove padding from the parent div will solve your issue.

```css
.static {
  position: absolute;
}

.static:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="margin:0;padding:2rem 2rem;min-height:100vh;display: flex;align-items: center;">
  <div class="row" style="display: flex;align-items: start;">
  <div class="col-md-4 p-0" style="text-align: center;">
    <img class="static" style="width: 85%;" src="https://cdn.makeawebsitehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/learn-code-e1455713167295.jpg" alt="image 1"><img class="active" style="width: 85%;" src="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/20/e5/programming_computer_environment_syntax_highlight_program_computing_display_hacker-1172040.jpg!d"alt="image 2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, distinctio, cum iusto esse pariatur consectetur eligendi itaque quos totam voluptas rem mollitia voluptatem veniam reiciendis omnis, saepe eaque animi qui.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Can't believe I hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 0):

add p-0 class for the outer div. hope this helps you. refer below link. thanks;

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/vbZebX`7777`